# Swift: Create a view on top of main view with buttons, textview, and datepicker

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am working on a project and my partner wants to eliminate the need for my second view controller and have everything on one view. What I have on the 2nd view controller is a date picker, two buttons, and two textviews. I imagine that the way he wants it is to have a rectangle pop up in the middle of the screen like a uialertcontroller and have all of that inside. and the rest of the screen is blurred.

My classmate created a similar idea to this but created it all programmatically, but I am not at that level yet. Is it possible to do it using storyboard? If so how?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you would use an alert view. I did something similar to this in a project of mine. Here something you could do:

- Firstly, if you want the new view to be shown over the old view, I would make sure the components are compact enough to make everything look nice. I would avoid having a view nearly as large as the old view, as you would just see a tint of a blurred overlay. I don't think it would look nice, but that is my opinion.
- Use something like the following to load your view from the storyboard:

  ```
  let newView = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myViewID")
  ```
- Now, in the function that you are calling to show the view, create the blur overlay:

  ```
  let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark))
  /
  if !UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled()
  {
      self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

      //always fill the view
      blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds
      blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
      blurEffectView.alpha = 0
  }
  newView.alpha = 0
  ```
- Add the new views to our view:

  ```
  self.view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
  self.view.addSubview(newView)
  ```
- Finally, we animate the views fading in:

  ```
  UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5)
  {
      self.newView.alpha = 1
      self.blurEffectView.alpha = 1
  }
  ```
- To hide the views after the user is done, use something like this:

  ```
  func hideViews()
  {
      UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations:
      {
          self.newView.alpha = 0
          self.blurEffectView.alpha = 0
      }) { _ in
          self.newView.removeFromSuperview()
          self.blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
      }
  }
  ```
- That should do it.

Comment: Thank you for an awesome reply

Comment: No problem, glad to help.